# constant for android HD contact photo size

Tags: android, constants, contacts, photo

i know android database keep two kinds of contact photo,
[[[  The photo may be stored in up to two ways - the default "photo" is a thumbnail-sized image stored directly in the data row, while the "display photo", if present, is a larger version stored as a file.  ]]]
the small one is 96*96 and the large is 480 *480
now the questions:

1. i still can't find the large one while the small one is "data15"in the database,someone please show me how to get the large one?
2. i need to place the photo on the first screen of launcher , so i need a photo at least 800*480,there must be declare constant for the photo size....

PS: I tried:

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
```

but when i opened the database , it became 96*57 ....confused.... some help changed it?

好人一声平安 (that's chinese-good boy,good luck)
thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean by storing the photo twice?
Yes, a lot of the devices out there will generate thumbnails, but thats more due to the fact that displaying thumbail images is a regular use case.

Have you tried fetching the user ID and using that to query the contacts data table?

This may be a long winded approach but, (pseudocode)

```
Fetch contact id using the URI RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
Fetch Photo id using the URI Contacts.CONTENT_URI
Fetch Photo using the URI Data.CONTENT_URI, the projection you want here is Photo.PHOTO (this will give you a blob)
```

Google should provide easy to read examples of these actions :)

Comment: thanks ,what i say store twice is ,when you crop a photo ,the device will first make a HD photo(480*480),this one is showed when you call;then the system will compress it to(96*96)as a small thumbnail shows in the contact list.

Comment: i've tried query in the data table."DATA15"is used to store the thumbnail photo.And I think the SmartPhone now have a better screen ,so (480*480) is not so (High Density),I wanna a (800*480) one....any advice?

Comment: @user2560471 Any chance you're referring to to taking a picture and cropping it before receiving it in the app via onActivityResult? If so, most phones will return a thurmbnail. You need to provide a file for the device to dump the uncompressed image into. I can provide code to point you in the right direction if needed.

Comment: i appreciate it ,eh ,i think it's better to try it by myself...i only want to know is the default contacts database doesn't provide a way to store a HD photo.And i'll add a extra item to store it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the larger image you can use the following code (provided you have the contactID):

```
public static InputStream getLargeContactPhoto(Long contactId, Context context) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
        return fd.createInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```